# Is there a way to hide iPad keyboard on safari (web browsers)

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad

Is there a way (jquery/javascript/css) to stop iPad keyboard popping up every time we focus on an input field. Idea here is to use on screen keyboards instead (like http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/mobile.html) as the iPad's keyboard takes almost half of the screen and this isnt required.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a variable `hideKeyboard` and call it whenever you need it:

```
var hideKeyboard = function () {
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $("input").blur();
};
```

Reference:

- [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement)
- [`blur()`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)

You could go with a plain Javascript alternative:

```
var hideKeyboard = function() {
 document.activeElement.blur();
 var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
 for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].blur();
 }
};
```

Comment: If this worked for you, don't forget to mark as answer

Comment: Actually, it still hasnt worked :). issue is the moment we tap on input field to write into, keyboard pop ups.  Will update you as soon as I get a solution

Comment: Updated. The following code should be working. Use psuedo css selector `:focus` too if needed!